# synchronized block within dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have seen code that dispatch async to a main queue or private dispatch queue (serial) and then in the dispatch code block is @synchronized.  Under what circumstance do you want to do that? Isn't a serial queue already providing the synchronization needed?

Can the synchronized block be replaced with another GCD dispatch?

Answer (score 3):

`@synchronized()` ensures that contained code (for a given token as the argument to `@synchronized`) is only run on one thread at a time.

Blocks submitted to a serial queue are executed one at a time, ie. a given block is not executed until all blocks submitted before it have finished executing. As long as a shared resource is only being accessed from code running on a serial queue, there's no need to synchronize/lock access to it. However, just because a given queue is serial, doesn't mean that other queues/threads (even serial queues!) aren't running simultaneously, and accessing the same shared resource.

Using `@synchronized()` is one way to prevent these multiple threads/queues from accessing the resource at the same time. Note that *all* code that access the shared resource needs to be wrapped with `@synchronized()`.

Yes, you can use another GCD dispatch instead of a synchronized block. The "GCD way" of doing this would be to serialize all access to the shared resource using a serial queue. So, any time access to the shared resource needs to be made, you dispatch that code (using either `dispatch_sync()` or `dispatch_async()` depending on use case) to the serial queue associated with the resource. Of course, this means that the resource-access-queue must be visible/accessible to all parts of the program that access the shared resource. (You essentially have the same problem with `@synchronized()` in that its lock token must be accessible wherever it needs to be used, but it's a little easier since it can just be a string constant.)

Answer (score 1):

The queue yes, it is synchronized, but if you access any 'external' object within, they are not synchronized.

If there are many threads, you know that each one will have its turn on the object. A tipical case is when you perform a CoreData import asynchronously, you have to @synchronized the context or the store coordinator.

Comment: You don't have to @synchronize an asynchronous Core Data save if you do it on a private queue.

Comment: On a private queue no, in that case only the store could be synchronized if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Thread-safe is about making mutable shared state either immutable, or unshared. In this case, `synchronize` and serial queues are ways to temporarily unshare (prevent concurrent access), and both are valid.

However, consider the case where you have disjoint sets of related info inside the same object. For example, a bill with 1) parts of an address (city, street, etc), and 2) price, taxes, discount. Both need to be protected to avoid inconsistent state (object A sets a new street, while object B reads the old city and the new street), but both are unrelated. In this case, you should use the lower level of granularity to avoid blocks between unrelated code.

So a rule would be: don't use synchronize on unrelated sets of variables inside the same object, because it would cause unneeded blocks between them. You can use a queue + synchronize, or a queue per set, but not synchronized on both sets.

The key is that `synchronize` refers to the one and only intrinsic lock of the object, and that token can only be held by once. It accomplishes the same goal as if you routed all related code through one queue, except that you can have multiple queues (and thus, lower granularity), but only one intrinsic lock.

Back to your example. Assuming that the object is documented as “state X is protected by `synchronize`”, the use of `synchronize` inside the queue is useful to block related methods that could access that same state. So maybe queue and synchronized are protecting different things, or the serial queue is there to perform a different task.

Another reason to prefer a queue is to write a more sophisticated pattern like a read-write lock. Example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *_dic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
dispatch_queue_t _queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.concurrent.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

- (id) objectForKey:(id)key
{
    __block obj;
    dispatch_sync(_queue, ^{
        obj = [_dic objectForKey: key];
    });
    return obj;
}

- (void) setObject:(id)obj forKey:(id)key
{
    // exclusive access while writing
    dispatch_barrier_async(_queue, ^{
        [_dic setObject:obj forKey:key];
    });
}
```

Comment: What is a barrier async? I never knew its existence. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A dispatch barrier allows you to create a synchronization point within a custom concurrent dispatch queue (it doesn't work for global queues). There are 4 variants: dispatch_barrier_[a]sync_[f]. The f is to run functions. They work like this: 1) You submit a barrier block to the queue. 2) When execution reaches the barrier block the queue stops until all blocks submitted before the barrier finish execution. 3) The barrier block executes alone (no other block is executing at this point). 4) The queue continues as usual.

Comment: I wish I could +1 again. But can you cite an example where one may use this dispatch_barrier_[a]sync_[f] goodness?

Comment: Barriers in any language or implementation are a synchronization tool for threads that cooperate and need to meet at a point. In numerical computation there are many cases where parts of an algorithm are inherently sequential and need the result of the parallel computation to proceed. A parallel merge sort would be another example.

Comment: "you lock the whole object for exclusive use of your synchronized code" "object can still receive calls from other objects" These quotes suggest that you think that `@synchronized` prevents all access to the object. It does not. It locks an internal lock associated with that object, but that only affects other code which attempts to take that same lock. That is, other code which also uses `@synchronized` on the same object. Code which messages the object without using `@synchronized` is not affected.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I rewrote in, I hope, less confusing way.