# Array was mutated while being enumerated - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        if (self.busStops.count > 0) {
            if (mapView.camera!.altitude <= 1000) {
                for (var i = 0; i < self.busStops.count; i++) {
                    if (MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position))) {
                        let stop = BusAnno()
                        stop.setCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position)
                        stop.type = "stop"
                        stop.title = self.busStops[i].name
                        stop.subtitle = self.busStops[i].street
                        self.activeStops.append(stop)
                    }
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.activeStops)
                }
            } else if (self.activeStops.count > 0) {
                mapView.removeAnnotations(self.activeStops)
                self.activeStops = []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above currently gives me:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',   
reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x1775edd0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

The reason this is happening is because if the user zooms out quickly whilst the app is still adding bus stops it commits to the 'mutated while being enumerated' error. The issue is, I'm not sure how to get around this, I essentially need to check if the app has finished adding bus stops before then removing them.

The aim of this code is to add bus stops to the map when zoomed in less then 1000 metres and then to remove the bus stops when they go above this altitude without getting this error.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322127/synchronized-block-within-dispatch-async

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid the "mutated while being enumerated" is not your biggest problem. You are also firing off new threads in rapid succession, because mapView:regionDidChange: can be called in rapid succession during zooming/panning. From the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:):

> This method is called whenever the currently displayed map region
>   changes. During scrolling, this method may be called many times to
>   report updates to the map position.

As a consequence, you are also adding the same annotations multiple times to the map.

Your algorithm should be something like the following. Note that this is just a sketch, it does not handle removal and it is probably not even valid Swift, I have never programmed in the language:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if (isUpdating) {
        return;
    isUpdating = true;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        var currentRect;
        do {
            currentRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;    
            var toAdd = [];            
            for (var i = 0; i < self.busStops.count; i++) {
                if (!self.busStops[i].isOnMap && MKMapRectContainsPoint(currentRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position))) {
                    // create stop
                    toAdd.append(stop);
                    self.busStops[i].isOnMap = true;
                }
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.mapView.addAnnotations(toAdd)
            }
        } while (mapView.visibleMapRect != currentRect);
        isUpdating = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your solution, `isUpdating` could be `false` while it is still updating.

Comment: @AaronBrager There is a race-condition due to which it might set isUpdating to false while an update is needed. But it cannot set `isUpdating` to false while still updating. Note that the only place it is set to false is outside of the update loop.

Comment: As far as I know regionDidChangeAnimated only gets called once during zooming and panning (at the end), when will it be called in rapid succession?

Comment: Oh I see, it calls it multiple times if you pan over and over with your finger

Comment: Many answers seem to have missed this and purely focused on the threads being the problem, your `isUpdating` solution fixed this problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The issue concerns thread safety. Your `busStops` array is being modified by 2 threads at the same time.

So you need to synchronize access to it, i.e. make sure that your updates to the `busStops` array are occurring serially (one after another) as opposed to concurrently (at the same time). One way to do this is to dispatch all modifications of that array to a serial queue that you create.

`dispatch_get_global_queue` will dispatch the above logic to a global shared concurrent queue. Instead of using a global queue, create your own and store it in an instance variable on the class.

```
_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.app.serialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

and then dispatch work to it as needed:

```
dispatch_async(_queue, ^{

    // Work, i.e. modifications to busStops array

});
```

If you want to get more nuanced, you could set up your queue as a concurrent queue, and use `dispatch_async` for all reads to the `busStops` array, and use `dispatch_barrier_async` for all writes. The latter essentially makes the queue behave temporarily as a serial queue.

Comment: I think you mean `activeStops` not `busStops` right?

Comment: I hate to ask for spoon feeding, but could I ask that you try and implement this solution the question's code, or at least just where to place the dispatch methods? I'm relatively new to Swift so this will help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @AlfieHanssen I am still getting the error when your solution is implemented like this: http://pastebin.com/HghrHP21

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought that would have worked. Are you accessing the array elsewhere in code, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to multiple thread modifying same object at same time.

There are two ways to fix this issue:

### 1) Method 1

Use:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0))
```

Instead of:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0))
```

But I won't recommend this way, because it can freeze your Main Thread

---

### 2) Method 2

Use `dispatch_barrier_async` custom serial queue and implement custom getter and setter for the array.

Declare a property like:

```
// For handling the read-write problem
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t myQueue;
```

In your `viewDidLoad` initialize it like:

```
_myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.midhun.mp.myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

And implement your methods like:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)
{
    dispatch_barrier_async(_myQueue, ^{
        if (self.busStops.count > 0)
        {
            if (mapView.camera!.altitude <= 1000)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < self.busStops.count; i++)
                {
                    if (MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position)))
                    {
                        let stop = BusAnno()
                        stop.setCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position)
                        stop.type = "stop"
                        stop.title = self.busStops[i].name
                        stop.subtitle = self.busStops[i].street
                        self.activeStops.append(stop)
                    }
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {
                    self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.activeStops)
                }
            }
            else if (self.activeStops.count > 0)
            {
                mapView.removeAnnotations(self.activeStops)
                self.activeStops = []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And change your data removing method is also using the `dispatch_barrier_async(_myQueue, ^{});`

Answer (score 1):

When I only look at the question, this is a thread safety issue.

You can use inter thread communication to let one thread know the status of another thread. E.g. by setting a variable via the notification system.

So in the loading thread you fire a Notification message as soon as all the bus stops are loaded.

In the receiving routine you do nothing (no zoom or what-so-ever) before you have received the Notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can synchronize access to self.activeStops like others have mentioned, but here's another easy solution too:

You could add your BusAnno objects to a temporary array inside the thread (I'm assuming iterating is the most expensive part in the code) and then flush them out to the self.activeStops variable back on the main thread (simply adding existing objects to another array will be quick).

This way you're only ever touching self.activeStops on the main thread, but still get the benefits of threading for updating it.

I also made it so the map view is not being touched inside the thread, because it is a UI element

NOTE: I'm no Swift expert so this may need some tweaks

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

    // Take a snapshot of the altitude and visibleMapRect so we're not accessing the map view in the thread
    let altitude = mapView.camera!.altitude
    let visibleMapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        if (self.busStops.count > 0) {
            if (altitude <= 1000) {
                // New bus stops added here in the thread
                var newActiveStops = [BusAnno]()
                for (var i = 0; i < self.busStops.count; i++) {
                    if (MKMapRectContainsPoint(visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position))) {
                        let stop = BusAnno()
                        stop.setCoordinate(self.busStops[i].position)
                        stop.type = "stop"
                        stop.title = self.busStops[i].name
                        stop.subtitle = self.busStops[i].street
                        newActiveStops.append(stop)
                    }
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    // Add to active stops on main thread
                    self.activeStops += newActiveStops
                    self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.activeStops)
                }
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if (self.activeStops.count > 0) {
                        // Also moved all map updates to the main thread (it's a UI element)
                        mapView.removeAnnotations(self.activeStops)
                        self.activeStops = []
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```